# How can i get zod to conditionally validate fields only if a boolean is false?

Tags: javascript, forms, next.js, zod

I have a form with input fields like this:

```
<div>
                        <h3>Doctor's contact info:</h3>
                        {errors?.doctor?.noDoctor && <p className="text-red-500">{errors?.doctor?.noDoctor?.message}</p>}
                        <div>
                            <input 
                                type="checkbox" 
                                id="noDoctor" 
                                name="noDoctor" 
                                defaultChecked={healthHistory?.doctor?.noDoctor} 
                                {...register('doctor.noDoctor')}
                            />
                            <label htmlFor="noDoctor">I do not have a family doctor</label>
                        </div>
                        <label>Doctor's name</label>
                        <input  className="w-full"
                            name="doctorName" 
                            label="Doctor's name" 
                            type="text" 
                            defaultValue={healthHistory ? healthHistory?.doctor?.doctorName : ''} 
                            {...register('doctor.doctorName')}
                        />
                        {errors?.doctor?.doctorName && <p className="text-red-500">{errors?.doctor?.doctorName?.message}</p>}
                        <h4><b>Doctor's address:</b>    </h4>
                            <label>Street Number</label>
                            <input className="w-full"
                                name="doctorStreetNumber" 
                                label="Street number" 
                                type="text" 
                                defaultValue={healthHistory?.doctor?.doctorAddress?.doctorStreetNumber} 
                                {...register('doctor.doctorAddress.doctorStreetNumber')}
                            />
                            {errors?.doctor?.doctorAddress?.doctorStreetNumber && <p className="text-red-500">{errors?.doctor?.doctorAddress?.doctorStreetNumber?.message}</p>}
                            <label>Street name</label>
                            <input className="w-full"
                                name="doctorStreetName" 
                                type="text" 
                                defaultValue={healthHistory?.doctor?.doctorAddress?.doctorStreetName} 
                                {...register('doctor.doctorAddress.doctorStreetName')}
                            />
                            {errors?.doctor?.doctorAddress?.doctorStreetName && <p className="text-red-500">{errors?.doctor?.doctorAddress?.doctorStreetName?.message}</p>}
                            <label>City</label>
                            <input className="w-full"
                            name="doctorCity" 
                            type="text" 
                            defaultValue={healthHistory?.doctor?.doctorAddress?.doctorCity} 
                            {...register('doctor.doctorAddress.doctorCity')}
                            />
                            {errors?.doctor?.doctorAddress?.doctorCity && <p className="text-red-500">{errors?.doctor?.doctorAddress?.doctorCity?.message}</p>}
                            <label>Province</label>
                            <select className="w-full"
                            name="doctorProvince" 
                            defaultValue={healthHistory ? healthHistory?.doctor?.doctorAddress?.doctorProvince : ''} 
                            {...register('doctor.doctorAddress.doctorProvince')}
                            >
                                <option value="" disabled="disabled">Select your province</option>
                                <option value="ON">Ontario</option>
                                <option value="AB">Alberta</option>
                                <option value="BC">British Columbia</option>
                                <option value="SK">Saskatchewan</option>
                                <option value="MB">Manitoba</option>
                                <option value="QB">Quebec</option>
                                <option value="NB">New Brunswick</option>
                                <option value="NF">Newfoundland</option>
                                <option value="NS">Nova Scotia</option>
                                <option value="PE">Prince Edward Island</option>
                                <option value="NT">Northwest Territories</option>
                                <option value="YK">Yukon</option>
                                <option value="NV">Nunavut</option>
                                <option value="US">USA</option>
                            </select> 
                            {errors?.doctor?.doctorAddress?.doctorProvince && <p className="text-red-500">{errors?.doctor?.doctorAddress?.doctorProvince?.message}</p>}
                    </div>
```

I am asking zod to validate the entire form, and it works great for all other input fields, but for this section of the form I want it to check if the checkbox  is false, and if so, then make the fields for doctor's name and address fields required. If the checkbox is checked, and the value is true, then these fields are not required.
I have tried several different ways to accomplish this, such as this:

```
doctor: z.object({
        noDoctor: z.boolean(),
        doctorName: z.string().optional(),
        doctorAddress: z.object({
            doctorStreetNumber: z.string().optional(),
            doctorStreetName: z.string().optional(),
            doctorCity: z.string().optional(),
            doctorProvince: z.string().optional()
        }).optional(),
    }).superRefine((val, ctx) => {
        if (val.noDoctor === false && !val.doctorName && !val.doctorAddress.doctorStreetNumber && !val.doctorAddress.doctorStreetName && !val.doctorAddress.doctorCity && !val.doctorAddress.doctorProvince) {
            ctx.addIssue({
                code: z.ZodIssueCode.custom,
                message: 'Please provide your doctor\'s information or select "I don\'t have a doctor"',
                path: ['doctor']
            })
        }
    }),
```

But none of the ways that I have tried seem to prove successful; no error message shows up at all.
I'm not sure if the validation is working or not, and if it is working, how do I access the error message to display in the form?
I should also mention that I'm using zod with Javascript, not Typescript.

The suggestions I have tried are coming from Copilot, but none of them seem to help so I thought I'd turn to the real users out there who may know how to deal with this type of scenario.

Thanks :)

Comment: Did you tried `discriminatedUnion`?